# .htaccess redirect non www to www exclude specific subdomain and cloudfront domain

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect as follows:

`mydomain.com.au` to `www.mydomain.com.au`

but not

`cdn.mydomain.com.au`

or

`mycloudfrontdomain.com.au`

I currently have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

It redirects everything to `https://www.mydomain.com.au`

Answer (score 0):

This condition is problematic:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
```

It says if `HTTP_HOST` doesn't start with `www.` and this will obviously match all subdomains as well. What you should be doing is making sure that `HTTP_HOST` value starts with `mydomain.` like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache completely before testing this change.

Comment: @SimonRivers: Did this work out?